# Boundary, closure, and interior of $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \;|\; x \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and }y>0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

> Find the closure, boundary, and interior of the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$:
>   $$
> A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \;|\; x \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and }y>0\}
> $$

It is clear that the closure is the whole upper place along with the $x$-axis as any point in this set must be a limit point of $A$. What I am puzzling over is the $\text{int } A$ and $\operatorname{Bd}A$.

The way I think of it is that as 
$$
\operatorname{Bd}A=\overline{A} \cap \overline{X-A}
$$
Now $\overline{A}$ is the entire upper plane so $\operatorname{Bd}A$ must be a subset of that. But $X-A$ is just the set of all $(x,y)$ with $x\in \mathbb{Q}^C$ and $y>0$. Then again any point in the upper plane is a limit point of $X-A$ so that $\overline{A}=\overline{X-A}$ then $\operatorname{Bd}A=\overline{A}$. Is this correct? I feel this just a special case of what I assume is the generalization: if $X$ is a topological space with dense subset $A$ then $\operatorname{Bd}A=\overline{A}$.

As for $\operatorname{int}A$, I am a bit more lost. I do not believe that $A$ contains any open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $A$ should be totally disconnected and singleton sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not open. Then is it the case that $\operatorname{int}A=\emptyset$?

Comment: What is $X$....?

Comment: $A \subset X$, where $X$ is any topological space. This is just the general definition of the boundary. Obviously, in this specific case $X=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: But $X\setminus A$ isn't the set of all $(x,y)$ with $x\in \Bbb Q^c$ or $y\leq 0$?

Comment: True, that is a part of the set I ignored. But clearly $\{(x,y)\;|\;x \in \mathbb{Q}^C \text{ and }y>0\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2-A$ since these too are points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ not contained in $A$. Even with your set added in we would still have $\overline{A} \cap \overline{\mathbb{R}^2-A}$ consist of the upper plane along with the $x$-axis. If I am correct about the boundary I should be done given the fact that $\overline{A}=\text{int }A \cup \text{ Bd }A$ and that would show my assertion about $\text{int }A$.

Comment: @KyleL your argument for the boundary looks good, although as Hamou points out there are some additional points in $X-A$ (this doesn't alter the argument). Showing that $\operatorname{Bd}(A) = \bar{A}$ can more or less finish the problem as you suggest: once you have this you can use that $\overline{A} = \operatorname{int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Bd}(A)$ *and* the facts that $\operatorname{int}(A) \cap \operatorname{Bd}(A) = \emptyset$, $\operatorname{int}(A) \subset A$ to conclude that $\operatorname{int}(A) = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition that the interior is empty is correct. To show this, you might use that [the complement of the interior is the closure of the complement](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complement_of_Interior_equals_Closure_of_Complement). Based on the work you've already done, I suspect that you can easily determine $\overline{X-A}$. (However, note that $X-A$ includes *all* points with $y\leq 0$).

It should be noted that $A$ is not totally disconnected, since it contains the "half-lines" $$L_q:=\{(x,y): x = q, y>0\}$$ for each $q \in \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that every open set in $\mathbb R^2$ must include points whose $x$-coordinate is irrational. From this and the fact that no point of $A$ has an irrational $x$-coordinate it is easy to conclude that $\operatorname{int} A = \varnothing$.

As for the boundary, using the "complement of the interior is the closure of the complement" idea from Morgan O's answer, it actually follows that $$\operatorname{Bd} A = \overline{A} \setminus \operatorname{int} A$$
(since $\overline{A} \cap \overline{ \mathbb R^2 \setminus A } = \overline{A} \cap ( \mathbb R^2 \setminus \operatorname{int} A ) = \overline{A} \setminus \operatorname{int}A$). So putting together the ideas from the other parts allows for a solution to this.